# Real world use of suckless's "sinit" init

Tags: init-script, init

I'm trying to set [sinit](http://core.suckless.org/sinit) as an `init` for linux (on a pc..). My goal at moment is simply running a single `tty/bash` from it. No special mounting is required as the kernel already gets a `root=/dev/sda2` for a `cmdline`.

I have `sinit` binary as my `/sbin/init` and I'm not sure what to do next.
I know that some scripts need to be placed, but I don't understand how `sinit` should be able run them, or associate them with `bash`.

Comment: And problem is...?

Comment: @siblynx added some needed lines .

Answer (score 4):

Included manual page sinit.8 as well as README is very explaining for me. However, a quick intro for you as I look into source:

- sinit main executable, `/sbin/init` gets started by kernel as pid 1
- it prepares initial environment to run `/bin/rc.init` script as separate child process
- it runs `/bin/rc.init` as separate process, thus, `/bin/rc.init` contain commands to initialize system beyond that point
- it enters infinite loop where it catches any zombified processes and reads their exit codes into nowhere
- while it in infinite loop, it however can be interrupted by signals. The signals it defines to be listened are SIGUSR1 and SIGINT. SIGUSR1 forces init to run `/bin/rc.shutdown` as `poweroff` script name, while SIGINT forces init to run same script with `reboot` name, to distinguish modes of operation inside script. Note that those two signals are only ones that init listens to, anything, **including** SIGKILL and SIGSTOP it will ignore. And only superuser is permitted to send signals to init. SIGINT is generated by kernel when you press Ctrl-Alt-Delete, but only when said so (there is a special syscall that init process usually does, to enable sending SIGINT on c-a-d)

So, out of this, sinit **does not provide**:

- init scripts (you have to write your own or adapt your distribution supplied ones)
- ways of control (like runlevels), only two simple commands

However, sinit is a nice cute small init that works. I bet it is very good on embedded systems as well as on simple desktop systems without modern desktop environments fuss.

Comment: Thanks @siblynx, your answer contians a lot of useful information, but it doesn't answer my question, probably because I didn't explain myself well enough. however, I understood my problam and I'll add an answer of my own.

Comment: Well I hope you understand that you need custom init script first for sinit. This topic is very wide and highly depends on your requirements, so I cannot cover it whole here. When you, for example, done writing your initial bootstrap script that does things like checking and mounting filesystems, console init, networking setup etc., you will place that script under a name `/bin/rc.init` and then make it executable: `chmod 755 /bin/rc.init`. That's all.

Comment: If you do not understand something - ask there, and I will try to improve my answer first.

Comment: thanks again, please see my answer. that should clearify what was my missing piece of knowladge.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, the linux kernel [parses](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/binfmt_script.c#L25) the [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) by itself.

Hence, any "Shebanged" script (with full path for binaries) could be used for `sinit`.

Comment: It's still unclear to me what did you asked for. If your problem was really how to "form" the shell script, then answer is clear: just putting `#!/bin/sh` as first line of executable text file will magically make it work like executable binary. But that's very old tech, anyone with even basic Unix experience notices this and then what's wrong with sinit is totally unclear to me.

Comment: @user140866 The rather non-obvious key to his question was in the very last sentence of the question: "how `sinit` should be able to run them, or associate them with `bash`". I didn't really understand it until I read this self-answer either. Sadly, many people who have been using Linux/Unix for decades never actually understand _how_ `#!` works. I've seen a professor teaching "Introduction to Unix" explain it as "it's just a comment" without any clarification, and have seen several colleagues whose jobs are Linux sysadmin and/or software development operate with erroneous ideas about it.